# Error on getting values from an array in a thread (JAVA GUI SLOT MACHINE GAME)

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I'm creating a slot machine game using java.After the user click the 'spin button' I need to get the values of the 3 pics which will be assigned to the 3 labels as slots in the GUI which is assigned by and array. But when i added threads to show the pictures changing in the array before assigning the last element to a slot, the proper values for the pics are not properly taken. instead it shows the values for the previous 3 pics which are assigned to the slots.

> GUI class

```
public class SlotMachineGUI extends JFrame {

private JLabel titleLabel;
private JLabel pcnameLabel;
private JLabel symLbl;
private JLabel symLb2;
private JLabel symLb3;
private JLabel creditTxtLbl;
private JLabel creditValLbl;
private JLabel betTxtLbl;
private JLabel betValLbl;
private JLabel winsTxtLbl;
private JLabel winsValLbl;
private JLabel lossValLbl;
private JLabel lossTxtLbl;


private JButton spinBtn;
private JButton resetBtn;
private JButton addCoinBtn;
private JButton betOneBtn;
private JButton betMaxBtn;
private JButton startBtn;

private JPanel pcPanel;
private JPanel btnPanel;
private JPanel mainBtnPanel;
private JPanel detailPanel;
private JPanel mainPanel;
private JPanel namePanel;


private int count = 0;
private int creditV = 10;
private final int maxCredit = 3;
private int picVal1=0;
private int picVal2=0;
private int picVal3=0;
private int wonCredit=0;
int val1=0;
int val2 = 0;
int val3=0;


private int credit;

public SlotMachineGUI() {
    setSize(800, 400);


    //to title
    titleLabel = new JLabel("--Slot Machine--");
    titleLabel.setFont(new Font("", 2, 30));
    titleLabel.setForeground(Color.decode("#FF0000"));
    titleLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    add("North", titleLabel);

    pcPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 3, 0, 0));
    pcPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);


    symLbl = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("src/cswrk2/clear.png"));
    symLb2 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("src/cswrk2/clear.png"));
    symLb3 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("src/cswrk2/clear.png"));

    symLbl.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
    symLb2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
    symLb3.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));

    pcPanel.add(symLbl);
    pcPanel.add(symLb2);
    pcPanel.add(symLb3);

    btnPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1, 0, 0));
    btnPanel.setBackground(Color.decode("#310138"));

    spinBtn = new JButton("Spin");
    resetBtn = new JButton("Reset");

    btnPanel.add(spinBtn);
    btnPanel.add(resetBtn);

    detailPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 4, 0, 0));
    detailPanel.setBackground(Color.decode("#000000"));

    creditTxtLbl = new JLabel("Credit Left ");
    creditTxtLbl.setFont(new Font("", 1, 14));
    creditTxtLbl.setForeground(Color.white);
    creditValLbl = new JLabel(String.valueOf(creditV));
    creditValLbl.setFont(new Font("", 1, 14));
    creditValLbl.setForeground(Color.white);

    betTxtLbl = new JLabel("Bet ");
    betTxtLbl.setFont(new Font("", 1, 14));
    betTxtLbl.setForeground(Color.white);
    betValLbl = new JLabel("0");
    betValLbl.setFont(new Font("", 1, 14));
    betValLbl.setForeground(Color.white);

    winsTxtLbl = new JLabel("Wins ");
    winsTxtLbl.setFont(new Font("", 1, 14));
    winsTxtLbl.setForeground(Color.white);
    winsValLbl = new JLabel("Wins Val ");
    winsValLbl.setFont(new Font("", 1, 14));
    winsValLbl.setForeground(Color.white);

    lossTxtLbl = new JLabel("Wins ");
    lossTxtLbl.setFont(new Font("", 1, 14));
    lossTxtLbl.setForeground(Color.white);
    lossValLbl = new JLabel("Wins Val ");
    lossValLbl.setFont(new Font("", 1, 14));
    lossValLbl.setForeground(Color.white);

    detailPanel.add(creditTxtLbl);
    detailPanel.add(creditValLbl);
    detailPanel.add(betTxtLbl);
    detailPanel.add(betValLbl);
    detailPanel.add(winsTxtLbl);
    detailPanel.add(winsValLbl);
    detailPanel.add(lossTxtLbl);
    detailPanel.add(lossValLbl);

    mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1, 0, 0));
    mainPanel.setBackground(Color.decode("#310138"));
    mainPanel.add(pcPanel);
    // mainPanel.add(btnPanel);
    mainPanel.add(detailPanel);
    add("East", btnPanel);
    add("Center", mainPanel);

    mainBtnPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 4, 0, 0));
    mainBtnPanel.setBackground(Color.decode("#310138"));

    addCoinBtn = new JButton("Add Coin");
    betOneBtn = new JButton("Bet One");
    betMaxBtn = new JButton("Bet Max");
    startBtn = new JButton("Starts");

    mainBtnPanel.add(addCoinBtn);
    mainBtnPanel.add(betOneBtn);
    mainBtnPanel.add(betMaxBtn);
    mainBtnPanel.add(startBtn);

    add("South",mainBtnPanel);
    setVisible(true);

    addCoinBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {


        }
    });
    spinBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {



            {
            Thread thread1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                Reel spinner1 = new Reel();
                //System.out.println(spinner1.spin());
                Symbol[] url1 = spinner1.spin();
                @Override
                public void run() {

                            for (Symbol symbol : url1) {

                                try {
                                    ImageIcon a=symbol.getImage();
                                    Thread.sleep(100);
                                    val1=symbol.getValue();
                                    symLbl.setIcon(a);



                                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                                    Logger.getLogger(SlotMachineGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                                }


                        }
                    }
            });
            thread1.start();

            picVal1=val1;
            System.out.println(picVal1);

            }
            {
                Thread thread2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    Reel spinner2 = new Reel();
                    //System.out.println(spinner1.spin());
                    Symbol[] url2 = spinner2.spin();
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                                for (Symbol symbol : url2) {

                                    try {
                                        ImageIcon a=symbol.getImage();
                                        Thread.sleep(100);
                                        val2=symbol.getValue();
                                        symLb2.setIcon(a);



                                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                                        Logger.getLogger(SlotMachineGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                                    }

                                }

                        }
                });
            thread2.start();
            picVal1=val2;
            System.out.println(picVal1);
            }
            {
                Thread thread3 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    Reel spinner3 = new Reel();
                    //System.out.println(spinner1.spin());
                    Symbol[] url3 = spinner3.spin();
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                                for (Symbol symbol : url3) {

                                    try {
                                        ImageIcon a=symbol.getImage();
                                        Thread.sleep(100);
                                        val3=symbol.getValue();
                                        symLb3.setIcon(a);



                                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                                        Logger.getLogger(SlotMachineGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                                    }


                            }
                        }
                });
                thread3.start();
            picVal3=val3;
            System.out.println(picVal3);
            System.out.println();
            }
            //symLbl = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("src/cswrk2/Banana.png"));

            if(val1==val2 && val2==val3 && val3==val1){
                System.out.println("samanaaaaaaai");
                wonCredit=((count)*picVal1);
                creditV+=wonCredit;
                creditValLbl.setText(String.valueOf(creditV));
                betValLbl.setText(String.valueOf(0));

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(startBtn,
                        "You won "+wonCredit+" credits",
                        "!!JACKPOT!!",
                        JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);



            }
        }
    });
    betOneBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            if(count<4){

                betValLbl.setText(String.valueOf(count));
                creditV--;
                creditValLbl.setText(String.valueOf(creditV));
                count++;

            }else{
                count--;
            }


        }
    });
    betMaxBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            creditV-=maxCredit;
            //creditValLbl.setText(String.valueOf(creditV));
            betValLbl.setText(String.valueOf(maxCredit));

        }
    });
    startBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });



}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SlotMachineGUI mainWindow = new SlotMachineGUI();
}
}
```

> Reel Class

```
import java.util.Random;


public class Reel {
    Symbol Cherry = new Symbol();
    Symbol Lemon = new Symbol();
    Symbol Plum = new Symbol();
    Symbol WaterMellon = new Symbol();
    Symbol Bell = new Symbol();
    Symbol Seven = new Symbol();

    public Reel(){


    }

    public Symbol[] spin(){
        Symbol[] symArr=new Symbol[6];

        Random r = new Random();
        for (int i =0 ; i<symArr.length ; i++){
            int randomNum = r.nextInt(6)+1;
            //System.out.println(randomNum);
            switch (randomNum) {
            case 1:
                Seven.setValue(7);
                Seven.setImage();
                symArr[i]=Seven;
                break;
            case 2:
                Bell.setValue(6);
                Bell.setImage();
                symArr[i]=Bell;
                break;
            case 3:
                WaterMellon.setValue(5);
                WaterMellon.setImage();
                symArr[i]=WaterMellon;
                break;
            case 4:
                Plum.setValue(4);
                Plum.setImage();
                symArr[i]=Plum;
                break;
            case 5:
                Lemon.setValue(3);
                Lemon.setImage();
                symArr[i]=Lemon;
                break;
            case 6:
                Cherry.setValue(2);
                Cherry.setImage();
                symArr[i]=Cherry;
                break;

        }
        }
        return symArr;


    }
}
```

> Symbol Class(implements from ISymbol interface)

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Symbol implements ISymbol {

    private int imgValue;
    private ImageIcon imgPath;

    @Override
    public void setImage() {
                //System.out.println("valur "+imgValue);

        switch (imgValue) {
        case 7:
            ImageIcon svn = new ImageIcon("src/img/redseven.png");
            imgPath = svn;
            break;
        case 6:
            ImageIcon bell = new ImageIcon("src/img/bell.png");
            imgPath = bell;
            break;
        case 5:
            ImageIcon wmln = new ImageIcon("src/img/watermelon.png");
            imgPath = wmln;
            break;
        case 4:
            ImageIcon plum = new ImageIcon("src/img/plum.png");
            imgPath = plum;
            break;
        case 3:
            ImageIcon lmn = new ImageIcon("src/img/lemon.png");
            imgPath = lmn;
            break;
        case 2:
            ImageIcon chry = new ImageIcon("src/img/cherry.png");
            imgPath = chry;
            break;  
        }
        //System.out.println(imgPath);
        //System.out.println("Image value "+imgValue);
     }


    @Override
    public void setValue(int v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.imgValue=v;

    }

    @Override
    public ImageIcon getImage() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return imgPath;
    }

    @Override
    public int getValue() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return imgValue;


    }






}
```

> ISymbol interface

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

 public interface ISymbol {
    public void setImage();
    public ImageIcon getImage();
    public void setValue(int v);
    public int getValue();


 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Swing GUI components should only be updated from the [Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

If you are trying to update the GUI repeatedly with a fixed delay in between, consider using a [`Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) to perform the GUI updates.  The `Timer` will fire an `ActionEvent` at the specified interval and that `ActionEvent` will be on the EDT so you can safely update Swing components.

If it takes a long, or indeterminate, time to determine which images to load (perhaps because they're being fetched from a service), then you might need to add a [`SwingWorker`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) into the mix to avoid blocking the EDT while you wait for the array of images to be returned.

(I'll update my answer with an example of how to use these in your code if you post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) - at the moment the absence of the `Reel` and `Symbol` classes prevent your code from compiling)

*** UPDATE ***

After looking at the SSCCE, it appears the problem has more to do with threading in general rather than interaction between the EDT and worker threads.  In the code below, I made a couple changes which I believe will address the problem you've described:

- Moved logic that checks for winner onto a separate thread, `resultThread`, which starts the three spinners *and* waits on their completion before determining if the spin is a winner.
- Removed the blocks around `thread1`, `thread2` and `thread3` so they could be referenced by `resultThread`
- Moved swing component updates to EDT through use of `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` (*note: this Oracle's recommended practice for interacting with Swing components, however I do not believe it's a fundamental part of this solution*)

> **SlotMachineGUI.java**

```java
            import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
    import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Font;
    import java.awt.GridLayout;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;

    public class SlotMachineGUI extends JFrame {

        private JLabel titleLabel;
        private JLabel pcnameLabel;
        private JLabel symLbl;
        private JLabel symLb2;
        private JLabel symLb3;
        private JLabel creditTxtLbl;
        private JLabel creditValLbl;
        private JLabel betTxtLbl;
        private JLabel betValLbl;
        private JLabel winsTxtLbl;
        private JLabel winsValLbl;
        private JLabel lossValLbl;
        private JLabel lossTxtLbl;


        private JButton spinBtn;
        private JButton resetBtn;
        private JButton addCoinBtn;
        private JButton betOneBtn;
        private JButton betMaxBtn;
        private JButton startBtn;

        private JPanel pcPanel;
        private JPanel btnPanel;
        private JPanel mainBtnPanel;
        private JPanel detailPanel;
        private JPanel mainPanel;
        private JPanel namePanel;

        private int count = 0;
        private int creditV = 10;
        private final int maxCredit = 3;
        private int picVal1 = 0;
        private int picVal2 = 0;
        private int picVal3 = 0;
        private int wonCredit = 0;
        int val1 = 0;
        int val2 = 0;
        int val3 = 0;

        private int credit;

        public SlotMachineGUI() {
            setSize(800, 400);

            //to title
            titleLabel = new JLabel("--Slot Machine--");
            titleLabel.setFont(new Font("", 2, 30));
            titleLabel.setForeground(Color.decode("#FF0000"));
            titleLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            add("North", titleLabel);

            pcPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 3, 0, 0));
            pcPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

            symLbl = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("src/cswrk2/clear.png"));
            symLb2 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("src/cswrk2/clear.png"));
            symLb3 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("src/cswrk2/clear.png"));

            symLbl.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
            symLb2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
            symLb3.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));

            pcPanel.add(symLbl);
            pcPanel.add(symLb2);
            pcPanel.add(symLb3);

            btnPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1, 0, 0));
            btnPanel.setBackground(Color.decode("#310138"));

            spinBtn = new JButton("Spin");
            resetBtn = new JButton("Reset");

            btnPanel.add(spinBtn);
            btnPanel.add(resetBtn);

            detailPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 4, 0, 0));
            detailPanel.setBackground(Color.decode("#000000"));

            creditTxtLbl = new JLabel("Credit Left ");
            creditTxtLbl.setFont(new Font("", 1, 14));
            creditTxtLbl.setForeground(Color.white);
            creditValLbl = new JLabel(String.valueOf(creditV));
            creditValLbl.setFont(new Font("", 1, 14));
            creditValLbl.setForeground(Color.white);

            betTxtLbl = new JLabel("Bet ");
            betTxtLbl.setFont(new Font("", 1, 14));
            betTxtLbl.setForeground(Color.white);
            betValLbl = new JLabel("0");
            betValLbl.setFont(new Font("", 1, 14));
            betValLbl.setForeground(Color.white);

            winsTxtLbl = new JLabel("Wins ");
            winsTxtLbl.setFont(new Font("", 1, 14));
            winsTxtLbl.setForeground(Color.white);
            winsValLbl = new JLabel("Wins Val ");
            winsValLbl.setFont(new Font("", 1, 14));
            winsValLbl.setForeground(Color.white);

            lossTxtLbl = new JLabel("Wins ");
            lossTxtLbl.setFont(new Font("", 1, 14));
            lossTxtLbl.setForeground(Color.white);
            lossValLbl = new JLabel("Wins Val ");
            lossValLbl.setFont(new Font("", 1, 14));
            lossValLbl.setForeground(Color.white);

            detailPanel.add(creditTxtLbl);
            detailPanel.add(creditValLbl);
            detailPanel.add(betTxtLbl);
            detailPanel.add(betValLbl);
            detailPanel.add(winsTxtLbl);
            detailPanel.add(winsValLbl);
            detailPanel.add(lossTxtLbl);
            detailPanel.add(lossValLbl);

            mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1, 0, 0));
            mainPanel.setBackground(Color.decode("#310138"));
            mainPanel.add(pcPanel);
            // mainPanel.add(btnPanel);
            mainPanel.add(detailPanel);
            add("East", btnPanel);
            add("Center", mainPanel);

            mainBtnPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 4, 0, 0));
            mainBtnPanel.setBackground(Color.decode("#310138"));

            addCoinBtn = new JButton("Add Coin");
            betOneBtn = new JButton("Bet One");
            betMaxBtn = new JButton("Bet Max");
            startBtn = new JButton("Starts");

            mainBtnPanel.add(addCoinBtn);
            mainBtnPanel.add(betOneBtn);
            mainBtnPanel.add(betMaxBtn);
            mainBtnPanel.add(startBtn);

            add("South", mainBtnPanel);
            setVisible(true);

            addCoinBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {


                }
            });
            spinBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    Thread thread1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                        Reel spinner1 = new Reel();
                        //System.out.println(spinner1.spin());
                        Symbol[] url1 = spinner1.spin();

                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            for (Symbol symbol : url1) {

                                try {
                                    ImageIcon a = symbol.getImage();
                                    Thread.sleep(100);
                                    val1 = symbol.getValue();
                                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            symLbl.setIcon(a);
                                        }
                                    });
                                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                                    Logger.getLogger(SlotMachineGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                                }


                            }
                        }
                    });

                    picVal1 = val1;
                    System.out.println(picVal1);

                    Thread thread2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                        Reel spinner2 = new Reel();
                        //System.out.println(spinner1.spin());
                        Symbol[] url2 = spinner2.spin();

                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            for (Symbol symbol : url2) {

                                try {
                                    ImageIcon a = symbol.getImage();
                                    Thread.sleep(100);
                                    val2 = symbol.getValue();
                                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            symLb2.setIcon(a);
                                        }
                                    });
                                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                                    Logger.getLogger(SlotMachineGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                                }

                            }

                        }
                    });
                    picVal1 = val2;
                    System.out.println(picVal1);
                    Thread thread3 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                        Reel spinner3 = new Reel();
                        //System.out.println(spinner1.spin());
                        Symbol[] url3 = spinner3.spin();

                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            for (Symbol symbol : url3) {

                                try {
                                    ImageIcon a = symbol.getImage();
                                    Thread.sleep(100);
                                    val3 = symbol.getValue();
                                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            symLb3.setIcon(a);
                                        }
                                    });

                                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                                    Logger.getLogger(SlotMachineGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    picVal3 = val3;
                    System.out.println(picVal3);
                    System.out.println();

                    Thread resultThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            thread1.start();
                            thread2.start();
                            thread3.start();

                            try {
                                thread1.join();
                                thread2.join();
                                thread3.join();

                                if (val1 == val2 && val2 == val3 && val3 == val1) {
                                    System.out.println("samanaaaaaaai");
                                    wonCredit = ((count) * picVal1);
                                    creditV += wonCredit;
                                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            creditValLbl.setText(String.valueOf(creditV));
                                            betValLbl.setText(String.valueOf(0));

                                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(startBtn,
                                                    "You won " + wonCredit + " credits",
                                                    "!!JACKPOT!!",
                                                    JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                                        }
                                    });

                                }

                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    resultThread.start();
                }
            });
            betOneBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    if (count < 4) {

                        betValLbl.setText(String.valueOf(count));
                        creditV--;
                        creditValLbl.setText(String.valueOf(creditV));
                        count++;

                    } else {
                        count--;
                    }


                }
            });
            betMaxBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    creditV -= maxCredit;
                    //creditValLbl.setText(String.valueOf(creditV));
                    betValLbl.setText(String.valueOf(maxCredit));

                }
            });
            startBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });


        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SlotMachineGUI mainWindow = new SlotMachineGUI();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you  @JasonBraucht for using your valuable time on this !! , I am new to the thread concepts, you did a huge help on completing this !!!

Comment: I'm glad it helped!  Keep in mind with multi-threaded applications, you won't necessarily know when (or even _if_) a given thread will complete.  There is a pretty good [threading tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) on oracle.com that I'd recommend if you are new to threading.